# No results from SOLR with haystack query, while data does exist

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I've got a configured SOLR server, which has all results indexed.
Querying all results does give records.

```
./manage.py shell
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> SearchQuerySet().all().count()
2086
>>> SearchQuerySet().all()[1000].result_top_level_category
u'tuinieren'
```

When I start querying for those records however, I got no results.

```
>>> SearchQuerySet().all().filter(result_top_level_category='tuinieren').count()
0
>>> SearchQuerySet().all().filter(result_top_level_category=u'tuinieren').count()
0
```

Could you give me a clue or solution to this problem?

---

The SOLR schema is generated by `manage.py build_solr_schema`. This is the relevant line for the `result_top_level_category` field:

```
<field name="result_top_level_category" type="string" indexed="false"
       stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Te issues appear to have happened after the SOLR schema was updated; another fieldname was reintroduced. This fieldname is returned though in the `all()` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes asking a question alone clarifies!

Looking at the SOLR schema documentation ( http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml ) it's clear to be that the field needs to be indexed to be queryable, or sortable.

```
result_top_level_category = CharField(indexed=True, faceted=True,
                                      model_attr='top_level_category', null=True)
```

Querying specific fields now works.